# ServiceThrottling default values?

Tags: wcf, default-value, throttling

**Hi,**

According to this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) the default values of **WCF 4.0** is this :

- **MaxConcurrentSessions:**
  16 * processorcount
- **MaxConcurrentSessions:**
  MaxConcurrentCalls + MaxConcurrentSessions 100 * processorcount
- **MaxConcurrentSessions:**
  100 * processorcount

I know, not that clear. When looking in the documentation at MSDN(**WCF 4.0**) it says this :

- **maxConcurrentCalls :** 16
- **maxConcurrentInstances :** 26
- **maxConcurrentSessions :** 10

If I however look at the **WCF 4.5** some of the values is based on CPU like the first example

- **maxConcurrentCalls :** 16 times the processor count
- **maxConcurrentInstances :** The default is the sum of the default value of MaxConcurrentSessions and the default value of MaxConcurrentCalls
- **maxConcurrentSessions :** The default is 100 times the processor count

So witch one is the correct one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before WCF 4.0 the default values were

- Concurrent Calls: 16
- Concurrent Sessions: 10
- Concurrent Instances: Concurrent Calls + Concurrent Sessions (26)

From WCF 4.0 onwards they are

- Concurrent Calls: 16 * processor count
- Concurrent Sessions: 100 * processor count
- Concurrent Instances: Concurrent Calls + Concurrent Sessions

Comment: For reference, here's an MSDN blog post that explicitly states the changes listed above that were made starting in 4.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/29/less-tweaking-of-your-wcf-4-0-apps-for-high-throughput-workloads.aspx