# WCF scalability with concurrent calls

Tags: wcf, concurrency, scalability

I have defined nothing in my configuration for WCF scaling. I'm targetting .NET 4.0, and I believe the main configuration I need to be aware of is [MaxConcurrentCalls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the default is 16.

The services haven't had their behavior changed - they are instance per call by default.

The services don't maintain any state and act as a facade to a more complex system. WCF is running under an IIS host and using either `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding` (both are in use, but not at the same time).

1. Do I need to increase anything other than the maximum concurrent calls?
2. What happens when you get the 17th concurrent call - is it queued (can't see answer on MSDN) or is it dropped?
3. Do I need to worry about setting values for `MaxConcurrentInstances` and `MaxConcurrentSessions` based on the above information?

Comment: Actually _[The default is 16 times the **processor count**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)_

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050(v=bts.70).aspx

Comment: No, < 4.5 the default is 16. 4.5+ raised it to 16 * processor count.

Comment: Ah didn't know they changed it.  Anyway it looks like .NET 4+  is _16 * ProcessorCount_ and prior to that it was 16. See  _[ServiceThrottling default values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614903/servicethrottling-default-values)_;  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/29/less-tweaking-of-your-wcf-4-0-apps-for-high-throughput-workloads.aspx